difference of 2 dates into days/weeks using php html
I have code which needs to state the difference of 2 dates from a table and display the range from start date to end date (in days and weeks) on the same table as well. How can I execute it? I have this code but it doesnt seem to do anything with the dates.The column names of the dates are 'date_started' and 'date_completed'. ex. 2024-07-01 to 2024-07-26
$datetime1 = date_create($_GET['date_started']);
$datetime2 = date_create($_GET['date_completed']);
$interval = date_diff($datetime1, $datetime2);

Then this is the echo that I put in the table:
<td>{$interval->format('%R%a days')}</td>

and the output is = +0 days
but I want the output to be = 3 weeks and 5 days

Show us what values are in $_GET['dateStarted'] and $_GET['dateCompleted'] when you run this code please. Then tell us what result you expected. date_diff calculates the time in between two dates. But your question says you want to "add 2 dates". So maybe you just used the wrong function? If you confirm the input data used, the expected result, and what also the result you are seeing currently, then we can help you a lot better. Also what does this have to do with SQL? There is no SQL in the code, and no data shown which might come directly from SQL.

P.S. Please read [ask] and how to make a [mre] of your issue. I never understand why people post questions asking about a problem in their data but then don't show us the data!! Please [edit] your post. Thanks

It seems to work for me: https://3v4l.org/XA2pC

@KIKOSoftware yes but what to do if i need to do it in all the dates in the table from the database?

If your database is MySQL you might want to look at DATEDIFF(). But your question is quite unclear about where the data is coming from. It seems to come from the URL, not from a database.

// make sure the format is correct
$date_started = '2024-07-01';
$date_completed = '2024-07-26';

// convert the strings to DateTime objects
$datetime1 = date_create($date_started);
$datetime2 = date_create($date_completed);

// diff between the two dates
$delta = date_diff($datetime1, $datetime2);

$totalDays = $delta->days;

// weeks and remaining days
$weeks = intdiv($totalDays, 7);  // int division
$days = $totalDays % 7;          // remainder

// to string
$formattedDelta = "{$weeks} weeks and {$days} days";

echo htmlspecialchars($formattedDelta); 

the output
3 weeks and 4 days

